# Find the average of inner dictionary keys after grouping outer key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary, eg;

```
dictionary =  {'cat_1' : {'age' : 5, 'height' : 15}, 'cat_2' :  {'age' : 1, 'height' : 7}, 'dog_1' : {'age' : 13, 'height' : 20}, 'dog_2' :  {'age' : 9, 'height' : 18}}
```

I want to find the average values of the inner dictionary keys for each type of animal, by grouping the outer id keys (using something like `key.split('_')[0]`).

Comment: What have you tried ? Also, can you give an overview of the desired output? I didn't get the part of `split['_'][0]`.

Comment: I think OP meant `key.split('_')[0]` which will give you animal type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this using `sum()` and `groupby` from `itertools` module:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = {'cat_1' : {'age' : 5, 'height' : 15}, 'cat_2' :  {'age' : 1, 'height' : 7}, 'dog_1' : {'age' : 13, 'height' : 20}, 'dog_2' :  {'age' : 9, 'height' : 18}}

animals, final = {}, {}

for k,v in groupby(sorted(a.items(), key=lambda x:x[0].split('_')[0]), lambda x: x[0].split('_')[0]):
    animals[k] = [j for _, j in list(v)]


for k in animals:
    final[k] = {"height": sum(j["height"] for j in animals[k])/len(animals[k]),
    "age": sum(j["age"] for j in animals[k])/len(animals[k])}

print(final)
```

Output:

```
{'cat': {'height': 11.0, 'age': 3.0}, 'dog': {'height': 19.0, 'age': 11.0}}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this, it uses `Pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dictionary)

        cat_1  cat_2  dog_1  dog_2
age         5      1     13      9
height     15      7     20     18

df = df.T.reset_index()

   index  age  height
0  cat_1    5      15
1  cat_2    1       7
2  dog_1   13      20
3  dog_2    9      18

df['index'] = [elem.split('_',1)[0] for elem in df['index']]

  index  age  height
0   cat    5      15
1   cat    1       7
2   dog   13      20
3   dog    9      18

df.groupby('index').mean().T

index   cat  dog
age       3   11
height   11   19
```

And if the output needs to be a dictionary then:

```
df.groupby('index').mean().T.to_dict()

{'cat': {'age': 3, 'height': 11}, 'dog': {'age': 11, 'height': 19}}
```

Comment: Nice approach using `pandas`, but it took some time (within my box) to finish processing the data. But, still a good answer. +1.

Comment: @ChihebNexus, what the size of your dataset ?

Comment: @Setop Really i don't know. I'm using an old Dual Core with 2GB of RAM.

Comment: @ChihebNexus can't you just tell us the result of a `len(dictionary)` ?

Comment: @Setop Same as the OP's dict. I think my current PC is the problem.

Comment: it took some time? this data is incredibly small, this took almost no time at all for me.

Comment: One more reason to buy a new PC :-) But still a good approach.

Comment: @ChihebNexus, sorry. I thought the comment was from the OP. Because I could not imagine pandas was slow on a 4 records dict. It is nothing. I used to work with many millions of records without any issues. Pandas use numpy which is written in C for critical parts and thus very fast and memory efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that might do:

```
dictionary =  {'cat_1' : {'age' : 5, 'height' : 15}, 'cat_2' :  {'age' : 1, 'height' : 7}, 'dog_1' : {'age' : 13, 'height' : 20}, 'dog_2' :  {'age' : 9, 'height' : 18}}

cats = dict((k, v) for k, v in dictionary.items() if k.startswith("cat"))

cat_count = len(cats)
cat_average_ages = sum([cats[k]["age"] for k in cats]) / cat_count
cat_average_heights = sum([cats[k]["height"] for k in cats]) / cat_count
```

You can just duplicate that for dogs or create a function returning the average values, depending on how many different animals kinds you have:

```
def find_average_values(animals_dict, animal_name="cat"):
    animals = dict((k, v) for k, v in dictionary.items() if k.startswith(animal_name))

    animal_count = len(animals)
    animal_average_ages = sum([animals[k]["age"] for k in animals]) / animal_count
    animal_average_heights = sum([animals[k]["height"] for k in animals]) / animal_count

    return {"age": animal_average_ages, "height": animal_average_heights}

dog_averages = find_average_values(dictionary, "dog")
```

Comment: this is not even a complete answer

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy what do you mean?

Comment: you only included how to calculate it for one of the keys in the dictionary not both, simply saying `you can duplicate that for dogs or create a function` is not a complete answer. the output of your answer should be the average across all keys.

Comment: what if there are horses or even animal one does not know in advance ?

Answer (score 1):

Another answer using `itertools.groupby` and `collections.defaultdict`. Has the added benefit of not requiring to know your inner dict keys.

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict

d =  {'cat_1' : {'age' : 5, 'height' : 15}, 'cat_2' :  {'age' : 1, 'height' : 7}, 'dog_1' : {'age' : 13, 'height' : 20}, 'dog_2' :  {'age' : 9, 'height' : 18}}
res = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))

# Group inner dicts by key
for k, g in groupby(d.items(), lambda t: t[0].split('_')[0]):
    for _, inner in g:
        # total the values
        for key, value in inner.items():
            res[k][key] += value

    # for each key average by the length of the dict
    res[k] = { _k : _v / len(inner) for _k, _v in res[k].items() }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option that doesn't need you to manually specify the keys is:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
from itertools import groupby, chain

dictionary = {'cat_1' : {'age' : 5, 'height' : 15},
              'cat_2' : {'age' : 1, 'height' : 7},
              'dog_1' : {'age' : 13, 'height' : 20},
              'dog_2' : {'age' : 9, 'height' : 18}}

animals_grouped = groupby(sorted(dictionary.items(),
                                 key=lambda x: x[0].split('_')[0]),
                          key=lambda x: x[0].split('_')[0])

animals_data_average = defaultdict(dict)

for animal in animals_grouped:
    animal_data_list   = list(chain.from_iterable(list(animal_data[1].items()) for animal_data in animal[1]))
    animal_key_counter = Counter([animal_data[0] for animal_data in animal_data_list])

    for data_key in animal_key_counter:
        animals_data_average[animal[0]][data_key] = sum([animal_data[1] for animal_data in animal_data_list if animal_data[0] == data_key]) / animal_key_counter[data_key]

print(dict(animals_data_average))
```